# RelativeLayout distorcido no Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

Alguém sabe dizer se é normal um aplicativo feito para celular Android, quando rodado em um tablet com sistema Android, ficar distorcido?

Algumas das *ImageView* do meu aplicativo ficaram distorcidas, umas ficaram maiores e outras menores, quando na verdade todas são do mesmo arquivo *@drawable/*.

Comment: Está declarando o `layout_width` ou `layout_height` como `match_parent`? Se sim, como está seu `scaleType`?

Comment: Estou declarando wrap_content em algumas ImageView, isto é errado?

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo você dar uma lida [nessa documentação do Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) que fala sobre as múltiplas resoluções. Na sessão `Configuration examples` pode ser interessante pra você.

De qualquer maneira, verifique como está o `layout_width` e `layout_height` da sua tela, assim como o [scaleType da sua ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: Ok. Vou analisar e trago retorno, desculpe não responder antes pois a placa mãe do meu note queimou. Só pude ver agora as respostas.